# Compute dissimilarity matrix on parallel cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-daisy

I'm trying to compute a dissimilarity matrix based on a big data frame. As my features are mixed with categorical and numerical features I need to use the `daisy` function in the [cluster package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/).

Any idea how I can run this in parallel cores? Below an example on the iris dataset:

```
require(cluster)

d <- daisy(iris)
```