# Compute dissimilarity matrix for large data

Tags: r, cluster-computing, r-daisy

I'm trying to compute a dissimilarity matrix based on a big data frame with both numerical and categorical features. When I run the `daisy` function from the [cluster package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/) I get the error message:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size X.

In my case X is about 800 GB. Any idea how I can deal with this problem? Additionally it would be also great if someone could help me to run the function in parallel cores. Below you can find the function that computes the dissimilarity matrix on the iris dataset:

```
require(cluster)
d <- daisy(iris)
```

Comment: Do you mind adding more detail, why this is not dupe? From a quick look it does look like a duplicate post but with extra info.

Comment: I fail to understand how you expect parallelization to help if you don't have sufficient memory. Have you estimated how large the resulting matrix would be?

Comment: I've closed your previous question.

Comment: I need actually to speed up the ```daisy``` function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570984/compute-dissimilarity-matrix-on-parallel-cores and solve the memory issues. It's good to separate these questions because this are two different problems

Comment: No, they are interconnected issues. Don't separate them. You can often solve memory problems at the expense of speed.

Comment: The dissimilarity matrix `d` has `nrow(iris)^2/2` elements. How many rows has your dataset?

Comment: These are my dimensions:

```[1] 465171     32```

Comment: And if I try to run the ```daisy``` function he tries to allocate 800 GB in memory.

Comment: Yes, you can reproduce the error with `x <- seq_len(465171^2/2)`. You don't have sufficient memory to hold the result of this operation. You could create the result in chunks ... But I'd question why you are doing this.

Comment: The main goal would be to apply a cluster algorithm that accepts dissimilarity matrices as input, such as ```pam()```. The reason why I need ```daisy``` is that I have both numerical and categorical features.

Comment: You need a smarter approach than brute force.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before. Running `daisy()` on even 5k rows of my dataset took a really long time.

I ended up using the `kmeans` algorithm in the `h2o` package which parallelizes and 1-hot encodes categorical data. I would just make sure to center and scale your data (mean 0 w/ stdev = 1) before plugging it into `h2o.kmeans`. This is so that the clustering algorithm doesn't prioritize columns that have high nominal differences (since it's trying to minimize the distance calculation). I used the `scale()` function.

After installing h2o:

```
h2o.init(nthreads = 16, min_mem_size = '150G')
h2o.df <- as.h2o(df)
h2o_kmeans <- h2o.kmeans(training_frame = h2o.df, x = vars, k = 5, estimate_k = FALSE, seed = 1234)
summary(h2o_kmeans)
```